# Padding a copied number without excel

Tags: vba

I've been searching around and can't find an answer to my problem. My VBA skills are very poor. So I'm using VBA with an internal system at my work, so not using excel. I'm using the following macro:

```
    ' Common variable declarations
    Dim ibmCurrentTerminal As IbmTerminal
    Dim ibmCurrentScreen As IbmScreen
    Dim hiddenTextEntry As String
    Dim returnValue As Integer
    Dim timeout As Integer
    timeout = 15000

    Set ibmCurrentTerminal = ThisFrame.SelectedView.control
    Set ibmCurrentScreen = ibmCurrentTerminal.Screen
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------


    ibmCurrentScreen.SendControlKey (ControlKeyCode_F12)
    ibmCurrentScreen.SendKeys ("224")
    ibmCurrentScreen.SendControlKey (ControlKeyCode_Transmit)
    ibmCurrentScreen.SendControlKey (ControlKeyCode_Erase_Eof)
    ibmCurrentScreen.Paste
    ibmCurrentScreen.SendControlKey (ControlKeyCode_Transmit)
```

So we copy a number from one program and want to check this in another program using this Macro. The problem is that the copied number needs to be 7 characters long e.g. "1234567" when we paste it, but sometimes the number we copy is jus 5 characters long e.g. "12345".

What I want to do is for the macro to add "00" before pasting it into the other program e.g. "0012345", if the number is shorter than 7 characters. Remember that this need to be done in the macro becasue we don't use any excel to hold the information in a cell.

My question is how to program this into the macro, the critical part is

```
    ibmCurrentScreen.Paste
    ibmCurrentScreen.SendControlKey (ControlKeyCode_Transmit)
```

Thanks

Comment: With leading zeros the number will be treated as text.  You could use `FORMAT("12345","0000000")` - does `ControlKeyCode_Transmit` hold the value?  `FORMAT(ControlKeyCode_Transmit,"0000000")`

Comment: No, i don't think the  `ControlKeyCode_Transmit`   holds any value. Try to just copy the number "12345" and with a macro add "00" to it before it gets pasted. One of the problems I don't understand is how to enrich a number that is just copied from any source with "00" before it gets pasted?

Comment: I can't see where you're copying - I guess it's one of the `SendKey` commands.  Rather than copying the number you'll need to place it in a variable - in Excel it would look something like `MyVariable = Range("A1")` meaning `MyVariable` now holds the value that was stored in range A1 at the time and you could use `FORMAT(MyVariable,"0000000")`  Maybe it's held in `hiddenTextEntry` or `ReturnValue` in your code?

Comment: So the mayor problem here is that the number could theoretically be copied from any where e.g Word, webpage or notes etc. The number is only stored in the memory i.a. copy the number then paste it, not in any cell in excel. Could the macro some how paste it in the formula and then add "00" or "0" to that number if it's less then 7 characters long? What I mean is that any enrichment ("00") must happen in the macro. Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using the [`Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function as follows:

```
ibmCurrentScreen.SendControlKey (Format(ControlKeyCode_Transmit, "0000000"))
```

Comment: I tried this  `ibmCurrentScreen.SendControlKey (ControlKeyCode_Erase_Eof)
ibmCurrentScreen.SendControlKey (Format(ControlKeyCode_Transmit, "0000000"))
ibmCurrentScreen.Paste
ibmCurrentScreen.SendControlKey (ControlKeyCode_Transmit)` and it doesn't work. I thinkt that the problem is how to add "00" to a copied number when it's copied from any source. How do I write the code so that the copied number gets "00" before I pasting it? Is there a code like `ibmcurrentScreen.(Format(Paste,"000000"))`? The number could also consist of 6 characters as well but should always be 7 characters.

Answer (score 0):

This solution solved my problem. Needed to take the information from clipboard. Note: The solution did not use Excel in any way which made it a bit difficult.

```
' retrieve the value from the clipboard
Dim textFromClipboard As String
Dim objData As New MSForms.DataObject
objData.GetFromClipboard
textFromClipboard = objData.GetText()

' Format the value to have leading zeros 
Dim formattedText As String
formattedText = Format(textFromClipboard, "0000000")


' Enter the formatted text to the terminal and hit enter
ibmCurrentScreen.SendKeys (formattedText)
ibmCurrentScreen.SendControlKey (ControlKeyCode_Transmit)

End Sub
```